# How to make sectioned listbox in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am making a grid (table) showing dynamic data in Windows Phone 7. I need to different sections of grids like a sectioned UITableView in iPhone.

How to make sectioned listbox in Windows Phone 7 ? Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are intend to build a [sectioned UITableView like the example shown here]. [1](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blogs/kevin_marshall/archive/2010/10/06/wp7-quick-jump-grid-sample-code.aspx). You can look at the [quick jump grid shared by Kevin Marshall](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blogs/kevin_marshall/archive/2010/10/06/wp7-quick-jump-grid-sample-code.aspx) or the [Bewise Phone Controls jump grid](http://bewisephonecontrols.codeplex.com/) and adapt the controls to suit your requirements.

HTH, indyfromoz